# MYSQL Cannot count the occurrence of a particular value in a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

So, there is an account number and we have daily information about their payments. Suppose we have information of 1 year leading up to today which is 08/March/2019, I would want to calculate the number of times he/she overpaid in last 1 week. I have used mysql window function but for some reason it does not seem to work

@GMB A sample data would look like this:Suppose for this account we have info from last march 2018. I just want the number of times paid_status = overpaid from the last date that I have on my file which is of today - 08/March/2019 and previous 7 days, 14 days, 1 month or any duration of my choosing. Your query will hardcode it only for 7 days.

```
ACCOUNT_ID paid_status amt dte
-----------------------
1234      overpaid   100 01/March/2018
.
.
.
1234      overpaid   120 01/March/2019
1234      not paid   0   02/March/2019
1234      overpaid   110 03/March/2019
1234      overpaid   120 04/March/2019
1234      overpaid   130 05/March/2019
1234      overpaid   120 06/March/2019
1234      overpaid   120 07/March/2019
1234      overpaid   121 08/March/2019
```

Query:

```
,COUNT(CASE WHEN paid_status = 'OVERPAID' THEN 1 END)
 over (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_ID
       ORDER BY DTE ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
 ) AS num_times_overpaid_week1
```

The output should be like this(not including today's info):

```
account_id num_times_overpaid_week1
1234               6
```

While I am getting multiple rows for the same account_id and it is not exactly calulating the field correctly

Comment: *it does not seem to work*: what issue do you meet exactly? Are you getting an error message, or wrong results? Also, it would be good if you could show us the entire query, sample data, current and expected results...

Comment: Please note that `ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` defines a window that contains the last 7 records, the current record *and all following records*. Maybe you just want the last 7 records and the current one? Then just: `ROWS 7 PRECEDING`.

Comment: @GMB I have added the sample data

Comment: Can you please show your entire query?

Comment: So in the resultset you just want one record for each account, with the number of overpaid in the last 7 days?

Comment: Yes, I would want one record for each account with the number of overpaid in the last 7 days

Comment: CREATE temporary TABLE dlq_hist AS 
SELECT distinct(LOAN_ACCOUNT_ID),
,COUNT(CASE WHEN DPD_BUCKET = '0.OVERPAID' THEN 1 END) over (PARTITION BY LOAN_ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY RPTDTE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 WEEK PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS num_times_overpaid_week1
FROM ACNT_HIST

Comment: I get 7/8/9 rows per account which is not exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data it seems like you are looking for a simple aggregated query (no need for window functions):

```
SELECT account_id, SUM(paid_status = 'OVERPAID') AS num_times_overpaid_week1
FROM mytable
WHERE dte >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY account_id
```

Expression `SUM(paid_status = 'OVERPAID')` uses a nice MySQL feature where conditions return `1` when satisfied and `0` when not.

---

NB: if, for some reason, you do want to use window functions (maybe to perform other computation), then you would need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank records by date, and the filter out only the most recent record per account in an outer query. I think that the definition of the window can be largely simplified:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        account_id, 
        SUM(paid_status = 'OVERPAID') OVER(PARTITION BY account_id) AS num_times_overpaid_week1,
        -- possibly other columns
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY dte DESC) rn
    FROM mytable
    WHERE dte >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Imagine there are 10s and 20s of such statuses and hence the need for window function? 

Can it not be done using window function

Comment: @Rohan: given your sample data, conditional aggregation, as shown in my answer, is the simplest way to go. Are you able to actually test the query against your data to see if it produces the expected output?

Comment: while your approach works perfect, the reason I want to use windows function is I can calculate lifetime sum, max, avg of multiple columns(in this case I added amt as a field). Using windows functions helps

Just for this overpaid thing I can write two sql queries and then join but I wanted to do it in one go. Appreciate your help, for example if I wanted to know the lifetime that this account holder overpaid -

,COUNT(CASE WHEN DPD_BUCKET = '0.OVERPAID' THEN 1 END) over (PARTITION BY LOAN_ACCOUNT_ID) AS num_times_overpaid

if I have it in one go, including last week(recency) it will hel

Comment: Added some more data and code above on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you so much, I have used row_number function in another query prior to this one, the point is I want to automate this to any time interval of my choosing be it 7 days/14 days/1month/3 months, apologies for not making it clear in the first instance

Comment: @Rohan: you cannot keep modifying your requirements like that... I helped you improve your question and provided 2 queries which I think are relevant for your use case. If you think that it properly helped you, please upvote/accept my answer. If you need more help, please consider asking another question (with relevant sample data, expected output and complete query *at first*... of course !). Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189638/discussion-between-rohan-and-gmb).

Comment: FWIW, I think you, and not the thread starter, dug this hole.

Comment: @Strawberry: would you please [explain more?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/189641/gmb-room?tab=general)

Comment: Why not simply ask for greater clarity at the outset?

Comment: @Strawberry: I did in the first place... See the comments in the original question. Expected output was added, then I answered. The thing is that requirements were changed *after* I first answered. Provided a second answer. When requirements changed again, I basically gave up... In chat, I tried to explain how to improve the quality of the next question... Apparently with [not much luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056362/mysql-cannot-count-the-occurrence-of-a-particular-value-in-a-specified-date-rang).